# Cannot install react-native-fs module on react native - windows

Tags: windows, react-native, npm-install, react-native-fs

I am trying to use `react-native-fs` in my react-native project (in windows)to read local file data in the device and the build fails.

After I ran the `npm i react-native-fs --save` command, the peer dependencies `react-native-windows` was not loaded. So I manually added it.

After which I am getting Error: Cannot find module 'fsevents\package.json' which is an optional dependency in Mac OS

I have not found any good documentation on how to properly add react-native-fs in a react native app in windows with visual studio.

Please help me with the steps to install react-native-fs module.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I solved it like the following:

```
npm install --save react-natve-fs --legacy-peers-deps
```

Comment: $ yarn add react-natve-fs --legacy-peers-deps
yarn add v1.22.17
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-natve-fs: Not found".